# Python - Sending hex array via UDP

Tags: python, sockets, udp, hex

Yes I know UDP is bad but unfortunately I have no choice - my server only takes UDP...

What I have is a list that contains hex values, need to send that out UDP.

If I try and send the list I get - 
  'TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list'

If i convert to a string (called aList in my code) I get - 
  'TypeError: an integer is required'
Print of aList = 09004000e3f00005f5

if I convert aList to an int with base 16 I get -
  'TypeError: must be string or buffer, not long'

Suspect it's something basic but I'm missing it.

Simple code looks like::

```
import socket   #for sockets    

UDP_PORT    = 21105;
UDP_HOST    = '10.194.34.151';


z21 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

def _getLocoInfo (id):
    arr        = [ 0x09, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0xE3, 0xF0, 0x00, id]
    arr.append(arr[5]^arr[6]^arr[7])
    return arr

msg = _getLocoInfo(0x05)
aList = "".join("%02x" % b for b in msg)

print (a)

try :
    z21.send(msg ,(UDP_HOST, UDP_PORT) )
     # receive data from client (data, addr)
    d = s.recvfrom(1024)

    print ('Server reply : ' + reply)

except socket.error as e:
        print ('Error Code : ' + str(e[0]) + ' Message ' + e[1])
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to python's socket module but looking at [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) page I feel you are missing two things:

- try using z21.sendto instead of z21.send
- try converting your message to a byte buffer with bytes()

So the result would look like this:

```
... other code

try:
  z21.sendto(bytes(msg) ,(UDP_HOST, UDP_PORT))

... following code
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well would you look at that.   Don't I feel like a dumbass.   That looks like it sends now but no response back so time to fire up wireshark.   But at this stage looks good.